# Please ID weed/grass

Tags: identification, weed-control, grass

I dug out all the moss in my backyard in early May and reseed with Scotts sun and shade grass seed. After a month there are some weed or some kind of grass growing. Just wondering what kind is it. I cut across the stem and is flat. The leaves are glossy on the underside and no hair or nodes. I have not mowed the lawn for over a month since reseeding. Should I dig it out or should I just leave it. I am in Pacific Northwest. 
Thanks for your help.

The Scotts sun and shade grass seed consists of 42% creeping red rescue, 34% turf type perennial rye grass and 24% Kentucky blue grass. I check on the internet, it looks like those weed/grass is turf type perennial rye grass. But I am not 100% sure.
It looks like the same as this :
[Is this a grass or weed or what type of grass?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/19773/is-this-a-grass-or-weed-or-what-type-of-grass)

Here are some pictures:
[image]

[image]

---

More pictures to show the stem.

[image]
[image]

---

More pictures to show the size.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This looks like one of the 3 grasses in the grass mix you planted. The varieties grow at different rates for a reason. The fast-growing grass helps shade and protect the more tender slow-growing varieties.

It does not look like a weed, or nut grass, or crab grass.

Comment: Scratch quack grass off the list as well; no auricles.